# git versioning file share

Tags: git, azure, azure-file-share

I am trying to have (git) versioning on a fileshare , but when running `git init` or `git clone` I get:

> error: chmod on /[my folder]/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted

Is there a workaround, or we have to use blobs versioning?

Comment: You have permissions to write stuff in that directory?

Comment: yes, I do have -- the problem is answer below actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the same problem already solved in [Prevent git from failing on filesystems without chmod permissions in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198321).

Basically `git` tries to do a `chmod` after it created the files and on filesystems where that is not allowed `git` fails.

The workaround is to create the repository on a different filesystem and move the files over after they have been created.

Sadly even the latest version of `git` seems to miss a command line option to disable that call to `chmod`.

Comment: yes, this is the issue, thanks -- the partition has type cifs

Answer (score 0):

> error: chmod on /[my folder]/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted

There are limitations on certain **Git** operations because they require file `system-level permissions` that may not be available.

I also tried to execute the same commands in **my VM** but faced the same issue, just like you.

[image]

In order to resolve the issue, try to run the same command with **sudo** or run the same commands from **the root user**

```
  sudo git init
  sudo git clone
```

**Result:**

[image]

When I try to run it from the **root user**, it's working fine.

> Note: If you create a user locally, try to add the same user to the sudo group for executing the git commands.

[image]